# Do most pre-medieval major scriptures have advaitic passages in them?

Tags: advaita

Scriptures denying Advaita started appearing around the time of Ramanuja.  But before that - do Vedas, Upanishads,Brahmanas, Aranyakas, epics and Puranas all have some passages in them that are advaitic?

Comment: Not sure of your question. Your title asks about 'without', but the second sentence in the body of the question asks 'with'. What exactly is your question?

Comment: No philosophy is new. Adi Shankara Bhagavatpada did not invent Advaita just as Madhwacharya didn't invent Dwaita. Everyone repeats what their preceptors taught them, and they themselves say so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are advaitic passages in scriptures. I am giving below one example.

> Yayati answered, '**The wise, with the help of the Vedas and of
> Knowledge, having ascertained the visible universe to be illusory,
> instantly realises the Supreme Spirit as the sole existent independent
> essence.** While that they that devote themselves to Yoga meditation
> take time to acquire the same knowledge, for it is by practice alone
> that these later divest themselves of the consciousness of quality.'

**Mahabharata Adi Parva, Section XCII**

Adi Sankaracharya did not invent Advaita although it was most probably not the most popular Vedanta school before him.

Comment: In fact the famous RigVedic passage "ekam sat viprah bahudha vadanti" can be take as advaitic - underneath multifarious deities lies undifferentiated truth (NOT some "superior" deity). @Pradip Gangopadhyay